# GUI frontend to extract ar archives

Tags: linux, gui, archiving, debian

I wonder whether there's a GUI available on Linux (Debian), that allows to me interact with old-style `ar` archives.

For whatever reasons, [Xarchiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xarchiver) doesn't recognize one of my `ar` archives (namely an MSVC import library, which is an `ar` archive, at least according to `file`).

I'm looking for something that runs on Debian/buster (so W32 or OSX solutions won't fit the bill).

Comment: Probably File-Roller or Ark will do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try 7-Zip. It can open and extract many archive format, including your old-style ar (*.a) format.

Comment: 7-Zip on linux with a GUI? (you probably missed that requirement, as I only used the *tags* to indicate it)

Comment: @umläute why? [see here](http://tomtomtom.org/p7zip-gui/) for the GUIs on Ubuntu, [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/7z/#Grafische-Oberflaeche) for another one (which is included in 7zip source and you'd need to compile it yourself, [see also here](https://www.ruinelli.ch/p7zip-gui-for-linux)).